# ttyUSB repeatable names

Tags: usb, tty, serial-port, ttyusb

Is there a way to have the USB ttys get a repeatable name like network interfaces have?

For example, usb to ethernet adapters used to be called "usb0" and such but now have a name based on their usb placement in the tree. (e.g. enp0s20f0u4u1u2)

I'd like the same for ttyUSB interfaces, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with udev rules.

Basically, udev allows you to match conditions of the new device, and it allows you to specify additional names for a device based on a set of device properties.

You don't mention what kind of repeatable you want, but you can have repeatable names based on the physical port or based on device serial number, or even both.